# Why am I getting IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, scrapy

Why am I getting this error?

```
motModel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[1]['value'] or None
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm scraping car listings and for this particular list there is only 1 item on the list.
In other words `motordata.get('displayAttributes')[0]` is there but `motordata.get('displayAttributes')[1]` is not there.

I thought that by using `i in range(len(my_list))` it would return a value if the key existed and move on to the next key/item if it didn't.

```
my_list = motordata['displayAttributes']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    motMake = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[0]['value'] or None
    motModel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[1]['value'] or None
    motYear = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[2]['value'] or None
    motMilage = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[3]['value'] or None
    motFuel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[4]['value'] or None
```

Comment: I do not understand what you do not understand. Lets say that your variable "my_list" is a list with 1 element. Even if you iterate, your code is trying get values from morodata.get('displayattributes') with indexes 0-4 where they may not exists. When your list has only 1 element, values with index 1 and more, do not exists. And you have proper exception. If you want continue such recipe be sure that value from motordata.get('displayAttributes') returns always a list with at least 5 elements.

Comment: I would advise asserting the length of the list first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is indeed not exceeding the range of the list:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
```

Within that loop, you can access list elements using `i` as the index safely.  But that's not what you're doing, you're using hard-coded index values:

```
motMake = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[0]['value'] or None
motModel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[1]['value'] or None
motYear = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[2]['value'] or None
motMilage = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[3]['value'] or None
motFuel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[4]['value'] or None
```

So "for each item in the list" you're telling the code to "give me the first 5 items".  You're explicitly telling the code to access the second item in a list that you know has only one item.  So, you get an exception.

It looks like you don't want a loop at all, since you're never actually using `i` and always over-writing the same variables in the loop.  Instead, check the length of the list before accessing each of the 5 hard-coded index values.  Something like this:

```
my_list = motordata['displayAttributes']
length = len(my_list)

if length > 0:
    motMake = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[0]['value']
if length > 1:
    motModel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[1]['value']
if length > 2:
    motYear = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[2]['value']
if length > 3:
    motMilage = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[3]['value']
if length > 4:
    motFuel = motordata.get('displayAttributes')[4]['value']
```